# Flat function with repeated sequence

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, pattern-matching

There are functions like `Join[ ]` that accept a variable number of arguments. `Join` is a flat function, as the order of arguments matters, but `Join[a,b,c]` equals `Join[a,Join[a,c]]`. I want to create a module that has the same behavior.

It's no problem to create a function with two variables. In this example nested lists are joined horizontally:

`JoinH[f_,g_] := Transpose[Join[Transpose[f],Transpose[g]]];`

How do I rewrite this function/module so that I can pass a variable number of arguments to this function, like `JoinH[a,b,c]`?

Comment: You mean something like adding the definition `JoinH[a_, b_, rest___] := joinH[a, JoinH[b, rest]]`?

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to write this in one line/function/ in a closed form without having two declarations of the same function?

Comment: Can you change the `Attributes` ?

Comment: I guess you found my answer useful.  I'm glad I could help, and thanks for the Accept.  However, waiting longer may encourage additional answers that bring a different perspective.

Comment: Alright, let's wait then ;)

Answer (score 4):

First, I'd like to point out that your "JoinH" function is already implemented by `Join`:

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
Join[a, a + 5, 2]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 6, 7}, {3, 4, 8, 9}}
> ```

Second, you don't need `Flat` or whatever if you write the function to natively handle multiple arguments:

```
jh[m__] := Transpose[Join @@ Transpose /@ {m}]

jh[a, jh[a + 5, a + 11]]
jh[a, a + 5, a + 11]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 6, 7, 12, 13}, {3, 4, 8, 9, 14, 15}}
> {{1, 2, 6, 7, 12, 13}, {3, 4, 8, 9, 14, 15}}
> ```

Third, you should also look at [the documentation for `Fold`.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fold.html)